# Array de Objects (não objetos) em Java - Como usar

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos

Tenho a seguinte tarefa a fazer:

Eu tenho três tipos de funcionários (`Commissioned`, `Salaried` and `Hourly`) e tenho que adicioná-los em uma lista (`ArrayList`) para poder geri-los.

```
ArrayList<Commissioned> c = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Hourly> h = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Salaried> s = new ArrayList<>();
```

Eu preciso que todos eles estejam em um único Array. Eu poderia criar uma interface Employees, implementar `Employees` em cada uma das classes e fazer um

```
ArrayList<Employees> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

mas não é isso de que preciso.

O que eu tenho que fazer, é

```
ArrayList<Objects> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

Porém eu não sei como trabalhar com estes empregados em um Array de Objects. Como usar coisas como ***instanceof*** ou casting de objetos.

O que eu gostaria de saber fazer:

Descobrir se um item desse `ArrayList` é uma instância da classe `Commissioned`, `Salaried` ou `Hourly`. E como usar os métodos de cada um dos itens do array, vistos que os métodos de cada classe são diferentes.

Obs1: Caso queiram ver como está sendo implementado o projeto atualmente: https://github.com/WilliamPhilippe/Projeto-de-Software/tree/master/FolhadePagamentos/src/com/company

- Esta em na classe Working Linha 11

Obs2: Pesquisei bastante na internet, mas não consegui encontrar coisas sobre Array de Objects, apenas sobre Array de objetos.

Comment: Willian Philippe: A pergunta possui algumas resposta. Ela lhe foram úteis? Caso tenham o ajudado considere aceitar uma delas. Leia [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Answer (score 5):

Criei três classes:

- `Commissioned`,
- `Hourly`
- `Salaried`.

Para simplificar o exemplo adicionei apenas um campo a cada classe:

- `Commissioned.name`,
- `Hourly.age`
- `Salaried.salary`.

Copiei os `ArrayList` `c`, `h` e `s` da sua pergunta e os populei com um objeto cada.

Criei o `ArrayList<Object> employees` e o populei com `c`, `h` e `s`.

**Não usei `ArrayList<Objects>`** como na pergunta pois [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) é uma classe utilitária constituída de métodos estáticos para operar sobre objetos.

Então para cada objeto em `employees` eu peguei sua classe com o método [`getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) e comparei com uma das classe `Commissioned`, `Hourly` e `Salaried`. Caso a comparação seja bem sucedida eu fiz a [conversão de casta](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) de `Object`para o tipo comparado e atribui um valor a propriedade intrínseca a cada classe.

Repeti o mesmo processo só que em vez de atribuir eu imprimi o valore já atribuídos a cada tipo.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        //Copiei da pergunta
        ArrayList<Commissioned> c = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Hourly> h = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Salaried> s = new ArrayList<>();

        //Popula cada ArrayList com um objeto
        c.add(new Commissioned());
        h.add(new Hourly());
        s.add(new Salaried());

        //Cria um ArrayList<Object>
        ArrayList<Object> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        //Passa "c", "h" e "s"  para employees 
        employees.addAll(c);
        employees.addAll(h);
        employees.addAll(s);

        //itera sobre employees
        for(Object employ : employees){
          //Faz a comparação do objeto com a classe
          if (employ.getClass() == Commissioned.class){

            //Faz a conversão de casta para o tipo adequado e atribui valor
            ((Commissioned)employ).name = "João";

          } else 
          if (employ.getClass() == Hourly.class){
            ((Hourly)employ).age = 30;
          } else
          if (employ.getClass() == Salaried.class){
            ((Salaried)employ).salary = 500.50f;
          } else throw new Exception("Objeto desconhecido");
        }

        for(Object employ : employees){
          if (employ.getClass() == Commissioned.class){
            System.out.println("Commissioned name:" + ((Commissioned)employ).name);
          } else 
          if (employ.getClass() == Hourly.class){
            System.out.println("Hourly age:" + ((Hourly)employ).age);
          } else
          if (employ.getClass() == Salaried.class){
            System.out.println("Salaried salary:" + ((Salaried)employ).salary);
          } else throw new Exception("Objeto desconhecido");
        }


    }
}

//Declaração hipotética de classes
class Commissioned{
    String name;    
}

class Hourly{   
    int age;    
}

class Salaried{ 
    float salary;   
}
```

Código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FrighteningDefiantPublishers)

Comment: Se eu precisar adicionar um novo empregado em "employees" eu posso fazer employees.add(newEmployee) ou eu tenho que adicionar em "c" ou "h" ou "s" antes?

Comment: Não é obrigatório. Na verdade você pode deletar "c", "h" e "s"  e ficar só com employees. Eu os usei para acompanhar o raciocínio da pergunta.

Comment: Há alguma razão específica para usar `employ.getClass() == X.class` ao invés de `employ instanceof X`?

Comment: @Douglas eu usei por conta da facilidade da leitura do código. Pessoalmente prefiro o uso de `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo sua lógica, poderia fazer assim:

```
ArrayList<Commissioned> c = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Hourly> h = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Salaried> s = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Object> employees = new ArrayList<>();

//Atribuição das classes a ArrayObject, e o que mais você quiser, String, Long, etc;
employees.add("Minhas classes!");
employees.add(c);
employees.add(h);
employees.add(s);

//Agora a leitura das classes, vou criar uma fun para setar os dados;
public void setItemViewType(ArrayList<Object> employees) {
    for(int position=0; position<itensMeusDados.size(); position++){
        if (employees.get(position) instanceof Commissioned) {
            ArrayList<Commissioned> c2= (Commissioned) employees.get(position);
        } else if (employeesTeste.get(position) instanceof Hourly) {
            ArrayList<Hourly> h2= (Hourly) employees.get(position);
        } else if (employees.get(position) instanceof Salaried){
            ArrayList<Salaried> s2= (Salaried) employees.get(position);
        } else if (employees.get(position) instanceof String){
            String titulo = (String) employees.get(position);
        }
    }
}

setItemViewType(employees);
```